# to_date in HANA with mixed date formats

Tags: date, format, hana, to-date

What can you do in case you have different date formats in the origin?

I have a case where we are using a `to_date` function to get the information from a table, but I am getting an error because some of the records have a date format `YYYY-DD-MM` instead of `YYYY-MM-DD`

How to apply a uniform solution for this?

Comment: How _could_ there be a solution for this? Sure, if the number is bigger than 12 it can't be a month, but if you see 2018-03-02, it can be both ways.

Comment: Do you have a second field in the table that defines the format is used? Without it you're pretty much up the creek.  Keep in mind if it's a date format in the system how it's displayed doesn't really matter.  However if the system is storing it as string data then yes you do have an unsolvable issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle this situation (arbitrary text should be converted into a structured date value), I would probably work with regular expressions.

That way you can select the set of records that fit the format you like to support and perform the type conversion on those records.

For example:

```
create column table date_vals (dateval nvarchar (4000), date_val date)

insert into date_vals values ('2018-01-23', NULL);
insert into date_vals values ('12/23/2016', NULL);

    select dateval, to_date(dateval, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as SQL_DATE
    from date_vals
    where 
        dateval like_regexpr '[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}'

    union all

    select dateval, to_date(dateval, 'MM/DD/YYYY') as SQL_DATE
    from date_vals
    where 
        dateval like_regexpr '[[:digit:]]{2}/[[:digit:]]{2}/[[:digit:]]{4}';
```

This approach also provides a good option to review the non-matching records and possible come up with additional required pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a case when in the select where you would test the different regular expressions, then use the to_date to return the date with the proper format.

This would avoid a union all and 2 select statements.

You could add more "format" without more "select" in an additional union.

Unless like_regexpr only works in where clause (I have to admit I never tried that function).

Comment: This seems to be a comment to my answer and not a separate answer to the question.

Comment: yes it, but I couldn't find a way to add it as a comment to your initial (my reputation may not allow me to do that yet).